# Passing null vs nothing to named parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my class:

```
class Source {
  final int value;

  Source({this.value = 1}) {
    print("source = $value");
  }
}
```

This is how I'm passing values:

```
Source(value: null); // prints null
Source(); // prints 1
```

The question is if I am passing `null` to `value` in first call, why doesn't it print `1`, aren't they equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

In your definition you are creating a [default parameter](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/javascript-conventions/how-to-create-default-parameters-for-functions/).

`value` is being defined as 1 and will be the default value in the absence of any other value being assigned to that parameter. When you actively provide it `null` as a value, it takes precedence over the default.

Answer (score 0):

@adlopez15 is the correct answer.

But if you want `null` to result in `1` you can do this:

```
class Source {
  final int value;

  Source({int value}) : value = value ?? 1 {
    print("source = ${this.value}");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it prints `null` in both cases not `1`

Comment: @iKeepChangingName Sorry, the problem is that you must print the field `this.value` and not the parameter `value`. Fixed it.